# How to use and export the scss independen in a react component library?

Tags: reactjs, sass, export

I'm use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library for create my library but I think that need use another package or use webpack but I don't know how I could make my components libraries using scss independently the React project.

Answer (score 0):

you can use loaders in webpack.
please search sass loader in web.

for example in webpack.config.js write this lines of code:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```